# Dummit and Foote Chapter 7.1 Exercise 20

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

**Chapter 7.1 Exercise 20**: Let $R$ be the collection of sequences $(a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots)$ of integers $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots$ where all but finitely many of the $a_i$ are $0$ (called the direct sum of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$). Prove that $R$ is a ring under componentwise addition and multiplication which does not have an identity.

I believe that I have found a counterexample, but I'm not sure if my logic is flawed somewhere. For $R$ to be a ring, $(R, +)$ must be an abelian group. However, for $A_1 = (1, 0, 0, 0, \dots)$, $A_2 = (0, 1, 0, 0, \dots)$, and so on $A_n = (0, 0, \dots, 0, 1, 0 \dots)$, where the $1$ is the $n$th component in $A_n$. $R$ is not closed under component-wise addition as the multiplicative identity $e = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^n A_n = (1, 1, 1, \dots) \not\in R$, as $A$ does not have infinitely many $0$ components.

Can anyone provide any insights?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Closed under addition means sum of **two** elemnets is still there in it. You cannot take infinite sums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axioms only guarantee closure under the addition of finitely many elements; nothing is said about infinite sums.

Induction can show that the closure axiom gives us that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \in R$ provided $x_i \in R$ for $i = 1,\cdots,n$. But that's it: notice that the upper bound is finite.

For a simpler example, consider how the rationals form a field (a special type of ring), but
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \not \in \mathbb{Q}
$$
even though every partial sum is in $\mathbb{Q}$.

---

*There is also a lurking, second, subtler question - how is the limit defined in rings? You would need some sort of notion of distance or topology to be able to define it, which you don't necessarily have. And that limit is very important for defining infinite sums, so this should be a second hint that someone's amiss...*